# How to understand logic in simple math?

Tags: python

So this bothers me a lot and I know the logic behind it but I seem to not comprehend this logic. Please explain the following.

When I write in Python this

```
x = 1
x = x + 1
```

it means x equals 1 (logic) but the 2nd line I was told that it says, "The new value of x is equal to the old value of x , which is 1 , + 1  "  this bothers me because in math you would not have a "new value of x and an old value of x" because x will have only one value.

Also I would replace the first x so it will be like 1 = 1 + 1 (because they are 2 x-s and I replace both of them with the value of 1) which is 1=2 which is nonsense but until now that is how I would think about it.

Comment: But programming is not math. Why are you trying to apply the rules of one to the other?

Comment: `=` operator is used for assignment. It means 'give x value 1'. If you want to check value you should use `==` operator. So `x == 1` means "tell me whether x equals to 1".

Comment: This is not an equation, but an assignation.`x = x + 1` means you are writting in `x` the value `x + 1`

Comment: In Python, and many other programming languages, `=` stands for [assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)), not equality (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Assignment_versus_equality) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Confusion_with_assignment_operators)). Other programming paradigms, such as [logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming), may represent formal logic concepts more faithfully.

Comment: Downvoted because this question is vague, badly formatted and written (enough to distract the reader).

Answer (score 0):

When you write `x = 1` that means you create a variable with the value 1.

When you write `x = x + 1` that doesn't mean you compare the two sides but if you want to do that,  you write `x == x + 1`, not `x = x + 1`.

`x = x + 1` means you want to add new value to x